# Setting Microsoft MyApps Header Logo

Tags: microsoft-office-365

can someone help me point to the direction on how to add a header logo in the `myapps.microsoft.com` website like below

[image]

Comment: I managed to change the header after checking the Microsoft Entra portal configuration.  It is located in `Company Branding` option.

Answer (score 1):

Login to your `Microsoft Entra Admin Center` and navigate to the following option shown in the screenshot
[image]